# How to store pure scala code

Tags: scala, serialization, akka

I'd like to use pure scala code (without side effects) as a immutable message for akka actor system. What form should I translate scala code to? Is the string representation the only correct method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pure scala code"? Are you trying to send a *function* as a message? Or just some code to compute a particular *value*? What do you plan to *do* with the code once it is received? Serializing functions is nontrivial, but I wouldn't be surprised if the akka people already have a solution for it.

Comment: pure function (corresponding to haskell definition of functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply send a scala.FunctionX as a message.

```
object Foo {
  val f = (s: String) => s.toInt
}

someActor ! Foo.f
```